# Restructuring PHP code in HTML

Tags: php, html

If this were just a static website, i would have four links

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 1</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 2</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 3</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 4</a></li>
```

But in this case the links would need to perform different callbacks, output messages and actions depending on who is clicking them. Right now, due to all this complications i have a very messy page. My code goes like this;

```
<?php
 foreach ($var as $key) {
?>
  <div class="content">
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 2</a></li>
       <?php
        if(session check){
             $var1 = the ouptut of some function
             $var2 = the output of another function
                  if(another check) {
           ?> 

                     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 3 type 1</a></li>

               <?php
                   } else{
                        if($var1 === something){
                  ?>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="somefunc()">Action 3 type 2</a></li>
                      <?php
                         } 
                         else {
                          ?>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class ="colorlink" onClick="somefunc()">Action 3 type 3</a></li>
                        <?php
                            }
                         }
 /* we are done with action 3 and now moving to action 4. Nb: still in the same session check */
        if($var2 == something){
       ?>
           <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="somefunc()">Action 4 type 1</a></li>

      <?php
        }else{
       ?>
           <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" style ="colorit"onClick="somefunc()">Action 4 type 2</a></li>
     <?php 
          }
/* Now thats the end of everthing in the session check */
/* This else is for session not active */
 } else{
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action 4</a></li>
     }
    ?>
```

I'm really sorry about how abysmal the indenting is, i really don't know how to indent on here. 
I was wondering if there's a better way to restructure the code, it doen't look as bad when it's been properly indented. 
The options i know of are, firstly,i wrap everything round a php tag and echo out the html but the problem is, it still looks as bad with all the nexted if statements.

The second option is the if:,else:,endif; construct, but that doesn't make it any better.
This is where i need you brilliant minds, how else i can restructure this code?

Comment: Just indent your code, paste it, highlight it and press CTRL+K

Comment: @doniyor The piece of code provided here isn't large at all. Anyone with a good enough knowledge of php will look through it pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Uchiha madara sama :)

Comment: @poepje who's doiniyor? lol, well this is the simplest way to explain what i wanted to achieve. I have many pages with over 500 lines each with this same problem, so that's not an answer my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into a [PHP Templating Engine](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/19-promising-php-template-engines/).  I use PHPTAL on a lot of projects.  Twig (not listed there) is also popular I think, possibly because Symfony is popular.

The goal is to keep PHP code with PHP code and prevent constant breaking in and out of php tags.

Comment: Ha this may be excatly what i'm looking for. Is PHPTAL ok to use with an MVC structure?

Comment: @SaffronHarris I would say it's even easier to use PHPTAL with an MVC structure than not, although it is a stand-alone templating engine (i.e. it's not completely automatic for MVC).  I've heard some criticism of PHPTAL too, so be careful with your choice.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks!! The example i'm seeing on there are excatly what i'm looking for, and it's easy to understand as well. But you've haven't had probs with PHPTAL right?

Comment: @SaffronHarris not any kind of problems I wouldn't expect from other templating engines.

Comment: haha i see what you did there hahaha, thanks Explosion Pills :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, cant you separate the PHP validation from the HTML and show and hide the Action buttons according to a validation function?

Check the code below

**HTML & PHP**

```
<?php
    $username = 'somename';

    function getmyclass(i,user){
       //return active or inactive according to the conditions
    }
?>
<div class="content">
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="<?php echo getmyclass(1,$username) ?>" onClick="somefunc1()">Action 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="<?php echo getmyclass(2,$username) ?>" onClick="somefunc2()">Action 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="<?php echo getmyclass(3.1,$username) ?>" onClick="somefunc3()">Action 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="<?php echo getmyclass(3.2,$username) ?>" onClick="somefunc4()">Action 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="<?php echo getmyclass(4.1,$username) ?>" onClick="somefunc5()">Action 4</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="<?php echo getmyclass(4.2,$username) ?>" onClick="somefunc6()">Action 4</a></li>
</div>
```

The get class function may return the class as `active` or `inactive` and if its inactive, the action button wont be displayed.

**CSS**

```
.active{
   display:block;
}

.inactive{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Very clever idea, which would definately be possible if this were a small project.However, the clasess are being used extensively, i only put an onClick event there to help explain what i wanted to achieve in a smaller scale. Thanks a lot :)